# Webpack can't find application.css in production

Tags: webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm having trouble setting up my Rails app in production, using Rails 6.

In development everything works fine, but in production, I get the following error:

```
Error during failsafe response: Webpacker can't find application.css in /home/dash-app/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
  "administrate.js": "/packs/js/administrate-b25a9656c7e053a1cf50.js",
  "administrate.js.map": "/packs/js/administrate-b25a9656c7e053a1cf50.js.map",
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-f21080d435da175878c0.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-f21080d435da175878c0.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "administrate": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/administrate-b25a9656c7e053a1cf50.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/administrate-b25a9656c7e053a1cf50.js.map"
      ]
    },
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-f21080d435da175878c0.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-f21080d435da175878c0.js.map"
      ]
    },
    "jumpstart": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/jumpstart-b8144fb92c8061b69d61.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/jumpstart-b8144fb92c8061b69d61.js.map"
      ]
    }
  },
  "jumpstart.js": "/packs/js/jumpstart-b8144fb92c8061b69d61.js",
  "jumpstart.js.map": "/packs/js/jumpstart-b8144fb92c8061b69d61.js.map",
  "media/images/icons/checkmark.svg": "/packs/media/images/icons/checkmark-94d128efd051661a94df22e517d9e626.svg",
  "media/stylesheets/icons/person.svg": "/packs/media/stylesheets/icons/person-3f49afb7a45c25f853507b0576fa783f.svg",
  "media/stylesheets/icons/twitter.svg": "/packs/media/stylesheets/icons/twitter-9cee238b819e63cb331309e217986742.svg"
}
```

My application.html.erb file containing this:

```
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

application.js:

```
...
import "stylesheets/application"
...
```

Running webpack:

```
...
[./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss] 664 bytes {application} [built]
...
```

Setting `config.serve_static_assets = true` doesn't work.

Most is build by Jumpstart, so I don't know where the problem lies.

Comment: did you do `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Results in `Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do`

Comment: try removing this `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`
` from application.html.erb.

Comment: I tried that. It "solves" the problem, but then my sccs doesn't get loaded and I don't know if that's a step in the good direction or in the wrong one.

Comment: IMHO, packs directory should only contain javascripts